# How to prevent WebAPI and OData from sending timezone with query results?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, odata

In the odata [documentation](http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#04-01-datetime-support) they state:

"By Default, converting between DateTimeOffset and DateTime will lose the Time Zone information. Therefore, Web API provides a API to config the Time Zone information on server side. For example:"

But when I write the code, my results are coming down with a Time Zone, I have not implemented the configuration identified in the documentation (as it is only meant to specify a time zone). Is it possible to send a property type of DateTime to the client without the time zone information? If not how is this accomplished without having to write code in the client to fix the data?

Comment: Send it at UTC, the timezone offset sent by odata should then be +00. Then you do not have to fix anything, just make sure your client understands to treat the datetime as UTC.

Comment: This doesn't work, I need the date to be immutable, meaning that it will show the same date in every time zone that retrieves the data, with UTC you still get a translation if the user is -05:00 then the date becomes the previous day.

Comment: Override the serializer and if type is datetime then convert to datetime without datekind and serialize.